# monodevelop 4 in ubuntu 14.04 closed unexpectedly when try to svn checkout or open old solutions

Tags: svn, ubuntu, crash, controls, monodevelop

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 in couple of computers and I experience the same problem in both of them.

When I go to version control menu to checkout a project even when I try to open an older version solution (ubuntu 12.04 - mono 3.1.0? I think) mono closed unexpectedly without any warning message.

If I try to create a new solution it works ok.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: run it from the console and post the error here

Comment: and explicitly say the **exact** version of MonoDevelop, "4" is just too generic

Comment: version 4.0.12 problem type crash Title MonoDevelop.exe crashed with SIGABRT in svn_stringbuf_ensure()

Comment: please test with monodevelop 4.2.3 and if you still experience the same error, file a bug in http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/

Comment: can you please provide some resources on how to do that? can't find any deb package for ubuntu 14.04 at monodevelop.com

Comment: you have to build from source

Comment: Done, upgrade to 4.2.2 from source and problem solved!

Comment: great, now you should bug ubuntu packagers to upgrade monodevelop versions in order to have less bugs!

Comment: The 4.0.12 in Ubuntu seems to have other problems too. Seems to be a very buggy build.